# PHP Artisan Tinker Cannot Write to Config Path

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, laravel-artisan, tinker

I have used Tinker before but suddenly it stopped working, no matter what project, what version, new or existing. I am on a macbook pro 2013, mac os Sierra, iterm2 with zsh. I have researched all over and not found anything of relevance with exception of one reference in stack overflow to https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/issues/382 which doesn't show resolution, is not laravel specific but seems to be involving the psy shell (all other artisan commands are fine):

vagrant@homestead:~/Code/application$ php artisan tinker

```
  [ErrorException]
  Writing to /home/vagrant/.config/psysh is not allowed.
```

Is the error I am shown. Vagrant is set up through virtual box running homestead-7.

When I ssh into vagrant and ls -la I see the .config folder but cannot access it nor can I mkdir mvdir due to access denied errors. (Which if I am learning from the stack trace below is where the error is being triggered? Top of the trace where the touchfilemkdir is at?) The folder itself is owned by vagrant. I can make out where the error is triggering but I don't know why it could possibly be triggering regardless of what version of laravel I use, whether it is an existing project or a new download.

Within the laravel projects themselves, I have

```
"laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
```

in the composer.json and

```
/*
 * Package Service Providers...
 */
    Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class
```

is located in app/cofig/app.php.

I did run a verbose stack trace though I'm not exactly sure just what it is pointing to as to what has broken or why.

```
Exception trace:
     () at
```

`/home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/ConfigPaths.php:213
 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at n/a:n/a
 trigger_error() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/ConfigPaths.php:213
 Psy\ConfigPaths::touchFileWithMkdir() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Configuration.php:361
 Psy\Configuration->setHistoryFile() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Configuration.php:409
 Psy\Configuration->getHistoryFile() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Configuration.php:546
 Psy\Configuration->getReadline() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Shell.php:82
 Psy\Shell->__construct() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/laravel/tinker/src/Console/TinkerCommand.php:53
 Laravel\Tinker\Console\TinkerCommand->handle() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29
 Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:87
 Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:31
 Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:539
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:182
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:264
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:167
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:228
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:130
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:122
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /home/vagrant/Code/lightpointLP/artisan:35`

If any other information may be required I'll be glad to provide it, I'm truly at a loss as to what has happened or how to fix it.
Thank you

UPDATE AUGUST 31
So I have found that when I am in vagrant@homestead and I sudo su when I then am in root@homestead:/home/vagrant# and I enter .config there is a configstore directory and a psysh directory but it was owned by root.  I changed the owner to vagrant, exited, reloaded vagrant and the same error.

`drwx------  2 root    root    4096 May  4 00:55 configstore
drwxr-xr-x  2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Aug 31 23:37 psysh`

So then I tried sudo -i and got root@homestead but found that the contents of .config were different.  This time it has .composer directory and no psysh existing.  So I added the psysh directory with vagrant as owner

`drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 Feb 26  2017 composer
drwxr-xr-x 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Aug 31 23:59 psysh`

but this still also does not work.  I also exited, reloaded vagrant, I config:cleared on both but I get the same unable to write error.

I am so at a loss, any insight would help, please.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Answer on https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/tinker-doset-work-in-shared-hosting?page=1&replyId=604794

```php
#You need to create a config file for PsySH with runtimeDir variable. 
# Just create a file ~/.config/psysh/config.php with:
<?php
return [
    'runtimeDir' => '~/tmp'
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an issue with PsySH  http://psysh.org/.

I can't answer the question but it looks like this guy had the same issue.  It may be worthwhile to get ahold of him and asked how he fixed it.

https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/issues/382

Have you tried running composer update?   Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I've done composer update, autoload cahche:clear etc.  thanks, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue and it persisted for days. I fixed it by running `composer dump-autoload` from the project directory. I previously tried the command but it didn't work because I was trying it without internet access, make sure you are connected to the internet when you run the command. Goodluck!

Comment: Yes, I had tried that a few times (with internet) , but it doesn't help.  I have since learned that Tinker does run under the artisan serve.  I may try it again though, just to see.  Thanks.  I'll post with results as I hadn't done it in awhile.

Answer (score 0):

I tried composer update, dump-autoload but nothing worked. Simply changed the permission on the ~./config folder and it worked. You can set 755 or higher (I am not talking about the production environment here).

Answer (score 0):

I've executed the next commаnd on my terminаl:

```
sudo chmod -R 775  ~/.config
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this solution?